# Find max value of a column and updating it in the same column if the value is zero

Tags: sql, plsql

I have table like shown below(attached the image of the table).

TableA:ID1 ,ID2 and Date columns are primary keys of the Table A.

```
ID1|ID2| QTY| Date
 1.  11. 10.   01/06/2020
 2.  22.  0.    08/06/2020
3.   33.  10.  15/06/2020
4.   44.  0.   22/06/2020
5.   55.  10.  29/06/2020
```

I want to find the max QTY value of a month ,then update that max value to QTY column which has zero value in QTY column.

Expected result

```
ID1|ID2| QTY| Date
1  | 11 |10 |  01/06/2020
2  | 22 | 10|  08/06/2020
3  | 33 | 10|  15/06/2020
4  | 44 | 10|  22/06/2020
5  | 55 | 10|  29/06/2020
```

Please note:Here date column is always need not be be monday's date.And if any month has for all the weeks, zero as QTY.I want to exclude those records from my query

Could you please help me how can I do it using PLSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set qty = (select max(t.qty) 
               from t t2
               where trunc(t2.date, 'MON') = trunc(t.date, 'MON')
    where qty = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Gordon.Here data is always need not be be monday's date.And if any month has for all the weeks zero as QTY.I want to exclude those records from my query. is there any way that is possible to achieve?

Comment: @user1917985 . . . What does "Monday" have to do with anything?  The `trunc()` is truncating to the beginning of the MONth.

Comment: @Thank you  Gordon.

Comment: @user1917985 . . . If this solves your problem, you can consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I have accepted the answer @Gordon , solution provided by you is working.Thank you